# How to search results from certain language in Google?

Tags: google-search, localization

As of today, I find that Google has changed its interface for filtering searched results to be from a certain language (such as Chinese).  I can't find a way to do that. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the settings menu by clicking the "Gear" icon (upper right). Choose "Languages".

Beneath the setting for the Google products language interface is a heading for "Currently showing search results in:" with your current language and an "Edit" link.

Click the "Edit" link. You should now see a long list of languages. Check the checkboxes against the languages you want to see results from, uncheck those you don't.